# Resgatar valores com nome de classes iguais usando Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Tenho uma situação no qual preciso resgatar valores de um *array* de `article`'s, porém não estou tento muito sucesso. Meu HTML está desta forma:

```
<section class="list">
    <article class="card">
        Article by Bigown
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        Article by Bacco
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        Article by Wallace
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        Article by Guilherme
    </article>
    <article class="card">
        Article by Marcelo
    </article>
</section>
```

Usando JAVA, consigo capturar apenas o valor do primeiro `<article>` passando a classe, porém não consigo pegar dos próximos porque as classes estão com nomes iguais. Vejam:

```
WebElement txtArticle;
txtArticle = driver.findElement(By.className("card"));
System.out.print(title.getText());
```

Retorno referente ao código acima:

> Article by Bigown

**Como eu queria** que retornasse:

> Article by Bigown
>
> Article by Bacco
>
> Article by Wallace
>
> Article by Guilherme
>
> Article by Marcelo

Como posso resgatar os valores de cada `article` mesmo contendo classes iguais usando Selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o problema está no find, no selenium quando você usa `driver.findElement` por padrão ele pega o first, neste caso você pode pegar `driver.findElements` por exemplo:

```
        List<WebElement> txtArticle = driver.findElements(By.className("card"));
        for (WebElement title : txtArticle) {
            System.out.print(title.getText());
        }
```

Comment: Cara, me tira uma dúvida. Como faço para pegar valores somente dentro de uma determinada div?

Comment: Vc pode pegar por XPath, por exemplo se tenho
```<div id="my_div>
    <a>a1</a>
    <a>a2</a>
    <a>a2</a>
</div>```
Para pegar todos os `<a>` de dentro desta div seria algo como:
`List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='my_div']/a"));`
Neste XPath ele vai buscar a div que tenha o id my_div, apos encontrar ele vai filtrar todos os anchors de dentro desta div. Ai com relação ao XPath, vc pode filtrar por outros atributos tbm, no caso se minha div tem uma class específica meu XPath pode ser `//div[@class='my_class']` por exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar o `find_element`, você pode usar o **`find_elements`**, que retorna uma lista.

Nessa lista, você pode chamar o elemento específico e dar o `.text`.

Exemplo:

```py
txtArticle = driver.findElements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card");

# retorno = "Article by Bigown"
print(txtArticle[0].text)
# retorno = "Article by Bacco"
print(txtArticle[1].text)
# retorno = "Article by Wallace"
print(txtArticle[2].text)
# retorno = "Article by Guilherme"
print(txtArticle[3].text)
# retorno = "Article by Marcelo"
print(txtArticle[4].text)
```